# Unity C# - Is there a faster way to load a number of image files from disk than UnityWebRequest, WWW or File.ReadAllBytes?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, image-loading

Its a VN style game with user generated content and I need to load the image without delay.

Due to it being user generated content the images will be siting in a folder with the game.
Due to the same reason I cant preload the images, since I cant know which will be the next image to load.

I have tried UnityWebRequest, WWW or File.ReadAllBytes and all have more delay than I expected, even thou Im running it on a SSD.

Is there a faster way?

The code im using for testing the loading time of the images

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// 2020/19/05 -- Unity 2019.3.3f1 -- C#
/// </summary>

public class itemCreatorImageLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image; // this is referencing to a UI Panel
    private Texture2D texture2D;
    private UnityWebRequest uwr;
    public RawImage rawImage; // this is referencing to a UI rawImage

// path = @"C:\UnityTests\Referencing\Referencing\Assets\StreamingAssets\Items\image.png"
// the @ handles the / and \ conventions that seem to come from the program using paths for the web
// C:/.../.../...   web
// C:\...\...\...   pc
public void LoadImageWWW(string path)
{
    if (texture2D)
    {
        Destroy(texture2D); // this follows the reference and destroys the texture. Else it would just get a new one and the old textures start piling up in your memory, without you being able to remove them. 
    }
    texture2D = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture2D = new WWW(path).textureNonReadable as Texture2D;
    image.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2D, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture2D.width, texture2D.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
    image.preserveAspect = true;
}

public void LoadImageWWWv2(string path)
{
    // "http://url/image.jpg"
    StartCoroutine(setImage(path)); 
}
IEnumerator setImage(string url) // this comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765518/how-to-load-an-image-from-url-with-unity
{
    Texture2D texture = image.canvasRenderer.GetMaterial().mainTexture as Texture2D;

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    // calling this function with StartCoroutine solves the problem
    Debug.Log("Why on earh is this never called?");

    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
    www.Dispose();
    www = null;
}



public void LoadImageReadAllBytes(string path)
{
    byte[] pngBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    if (texture2D)
    {
        Destroy(texture2D); // this follows the reference and destroys the texture. Else it would just get a new one and the old textures start piling up in your memory, without you being able to remove them. 
    }
    texture2D = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture2D.LoadImage(pngBytes);

    image.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2D as Texture2D, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture2D.width, texture2D.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
    image.preserveAspect = true;
}

public void LoadImageUnityWebRequest(string path)
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadImageCorroutine());
    IEnumerator LoadImageCorroutine()
    {
        using (uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(@path))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            // I would always check for errors first
            if (uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Could not load texture do to {uwr.responseCode} - \"{uwr.error}\"", this);
                yield break;
            }
            // Destroy the current texture instance
            if (rawImage.texture)
            {
                Destroy(texture2D); // this follows the reference and destroys the texture. Else it would just get a new one and the old textures start piling up in your memory, without you being able to remove them.
            }
            rawImage.texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
            image.sprite = Sprite.Create(rawImage.texture as Texture2D, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, rawImage.texture.width, rawImage.texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
            image.preserveAspect = true;
        }
        StopCoroutine(LoadImageCorroutine());
    }
}


public void LoadImageUnityWebRequestv2(string path)
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadImageUnityWebRequestv2Coroutine(path));
}
IEnumerator LoadImageUnityWebRequestv2Coroutine(string MediaUrl) // this comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765518/how-to-load-an-image-from-url-with-unity
{
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(MediaUrl);
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
    else
        {
            rawImage.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
        }
}



// a async version that I grabbed from somewhere, but I dont remember where anymore 
[SerializeField] string _imageUrl;
[SerializeField] Material _material;

public async void MyFunction()
{
    Texture2D texture = await GetRemoteTexture(_imageUrl);
    _material.mainTexture = texture;
}
public static async Task<Texture2D> GetRemoteTexture(string url)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
    {
        //begin requenst:
        var asyncOp = www.SendWebRequest();

        //await until it's done: 
        while (asyncOp.isDone == false)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000 / 30);//30 hertz
        }

        //read results:
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            //log error:
            #if DEBUG
            Debug.Log($"{ www.error }, URL:{ www.url }");
            #endif

            //nothing to return on error:
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            //return valid results:
            return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks - https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/208707516-Why-should-I-use-Threads-instead-of-Coroutines-

Answer (score 0):

I use and like a Unity-friendly await/async support suite called [ProtoPromise](https://github.com/timcassell/ProtoPromise).  It's a great answer to vanilla Unity C# async/await since it has a lot of optimizations that reduce load on the GC, such as pooling (allocation-free async calls).  Tim is also a friendly and attentive guy who cares about his code, making it stable, making it capable, and making it fast.

That said, here's my image loading code. It performs well across platforms and wraps both web-based and file based Texture loading.

```
using Proto.Promises;
using Proto.Promises.Threading;

public interface IAssetResponder {
    void                        OnAssetResolved<T>(AssetReq<T> request) where T : UnityEngine.Object;
}

public struct AssetReq<T> where T : UnityEngine.Object {
    public AssetRef             AssetRef;  // what to load
    public IAssetResponder      Responder; // receives OnAssetRequestComplete
    public UnityEngine.Object   Asset;     // Init to null; 
    public string               ErrMsg;    // null denotes success
 
    public bool                 IsComplete => ErrMsg != null || Asset != null;
    
    public                      AssetReq(IAssetResponder responder, AssetRef assetRef, LoadAssetOpts opts = LoadAssetOpts.None) {
        AssetRef = assetRef;
        Responder = responder;
        Opts = opts;
        Asset = null;
        ErrMsg = null;
    }
    
    public void                 Resolve(UnityEngine.Object obj) {
        if (!TryResolve(obj)) {
            if (obj == null) {
                Fail("Asset is null");
            } else {
                Fail($"Asset of type {obj.GetType().Name} could not be resolved to type {typeof(T).Name}");
            }
        }

    }
    
    public bool                 TryResolve(UnityEngine.Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        
        if (obj is T assetAsT) {
            Asset = assetAsT;
            return true;
        } else if (obj is Texture2D tex2D) {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(ArcGlyph)) 
                Asset = tex2D;
        } else if (obj is Sprite sprite) {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Sprite)) 
                Asset = sprite;
        }
        
        if (this.Asset != null) {
            Responder.OnAssetResolved(this);
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    public void                 Fail(string err) {
        ErrMsg = err;
        Responder.OnAssetResolved(this);
    }
}

public class AssetService : MonoBehaviour {
 
    public bool                 TryResolveAsset<T>(AssetReq<T> req) where T : UnityEngine.Object {
        ...
    }

    ...

    AsyncSemaphore _maxFileLoads = new AsyncSemaphore(8);
    AsyncSemaphore _maxWebReqs   = new AsyncSemaphore(3);

    async Promise loadTextureFromFile<T>(string pathname, AssetReq<T> texReq) where T : UnityEngine.Object {
        await Promise.SwitchToBackground();
        
        byte[] texData = null;
        using (await _maxFileLoads.EnterScopeAsync()) {
            if (!texReq.AssetRef.GetURIForScheme(URIScheme.File, out pathname)) {
                texReq.Fail($"failed to get pathname for AssetRef '{texReq.AssetRef}'");
                return;
            }
            try {
                texData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                texReq.Fail($"failed to read '{pathname}': {e.Message}");
                return;
            }
        }
        
        await Promise.SwitchToForeground();

        Texture2D tex2D = new Texture2D(1,1);
        if (tex2D.LoadImage(texData)) {
            texReq.Resolve(tex2D);
        } else {
            texReq.Fail($"failed to load texture from file '{pathname}'");
        }
    }

    async Promise loadTextureUsingWebRequest<T>(AssetReq<T> req) where T : UnityEngine.Object {
        using (await _maxWebReqs.EnterScopeAsync()) {
            var url = req.AssetRef.URL;
            using (var webReq = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url, false)) {
                await PromiseYielder.WaitForAsyncOperation(webReq.SendWebRequest());
                
                if (webReq.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
                    req.Resolve(((DownloadHandlerTexture) webReq.downloadHandler).texture);
                } else {
                    req.Fail(webReq.error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```