# How to get an image from a url and set it to an object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method to create objects from prefabs. The prefab consists of the texts "Title" and "Description", as well as the image "Image".
[image]

In the method below, I get the text for "Title", "Description" and the URL of the image for "Image".

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class CreateMonumentButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform prefarb;
    public RectTransform content;

    private string City;
    private string URL = DataHolders.URL;

    async private void Awake()
    {
        City = DataHolders.City;
        StartCoroutine(Get());
    }

    void InitializeItemView (GameObject viewGameObject, string TextTitle, string TextDescription, string URLImg)
    {
        TestItemView view = new TestItemView(viewGameObject.transform);
        view.Title.text = TextTitle;
        view.Description.text = TextDescription;

        File fileData;
        Texture2d txture;
        (File.Exists(URLImg))     {
            fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(URLImg); //read the bytes from the file at URLImg's destination
            txture = new Texture2D(0,0);//makes the new texture
            txture.LoadImage(fileData);//loads the image from the file
            view.Img.sprite = Sprite.Create(txture, new Rect(0,0,200,200), new Vector2());
            //set Img.sprite to a new sprite at 0,0 with the dimensions 200x200
        }
    }

    public class TestItemView
    {
        public Text Title;
        public Text Description;
        // public Image Image;

        public TestItemView (Transform rootView)
        {
            Title = rootView.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>();
            Description = rootView.Find("Description").GetComponent<Text>();
            // Image = rootView.Find("Image").GetComponent<Image>();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Get()
    {
        WWWForm formT = new WWWForm();

        formT.AddField("City", City);

        WWW wwwT = new WWW(URL + "get_monuments.php", formT);
        yield return wwwT;
        if (wwwT.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ошибка: " + wwwT.error);
            yield break;
        }

        WWWForm formD = new WWWForm();

        formD.AddField("City", City);

        WWW wwwD = new WWW(URL + "get_description.php", formD);
        yield return wwwD;
        if (wwwD.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ошибка: " + wwwD.error);
            yield break;
        }

        WWWForm formI = new WWWForm();

        formI.AddField("City", City);

        WWW wwwI = new WWW(URL + "get_img.php", formI);
        yield return wwwI;
        if (wwwI.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ошибка: " + wwwI.error);
            yield break;
        }

        WWWForm formL = new WWWForm();

        formL.AddField("City", City);

        WWW wwwL = new WWW(URL + "get_lenLists.php", formL);
        yield return wwwL;
        if (wwwL.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ошибка: " + wwwL.error);
            yield break;
        }

        DataHolders.listLen = int.Parse(wwwL.text);
        DataHolders.listImg = wwwI.text;
        DataHolders.listDescription = wwwD.text;  
        DataHolders.listMonuments = wwwT.text; 

        var ListTitls = JObject.Parse(DataHolders.listMonuments);
        var ListDescriptions = JObject.Parse(DataHolders.listDescription);
        var ListImgs = JObject.Parse(DataHolders.listImg);

        for( int i = 0; i < DataHolders.listLen; i++ )
        {
            // Debug.Log(i.ToString());
            var Title = (string) ListTitls[i.ToString()];
            var Description = (string) ListDescriptions[i.ToString()];
            var Img = (string) ListImgs[i.ToString()];

            var instance = GameObject.Instantiate(prefarb.gameObject) as GameObject;
            instance.transform.SetParent(content, false);
            InitializeItemView(instance, Title, Description, Img);
        }      
    }
}
```

I don't understand how can I get an image from an image url and set its value to "Image".
[image]

But I am a beginner, so it is desirable that you explain something in simple terms.

Comment: It can be Googled as `unity image from url`, some links: [forum 2020](https://forum.unity.com/threads/image-from-url.1052135/), [stackoverflow question 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765518/how-to-load-an-image-from-url-with-unity)

Comment: [Retrieving a Texture from an HTTP Server (GET)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html)

Answer (score 0):

Image doesn't have an attribute of Text, and instead you should get the file, load the image to a texture and set the Image's sprite as the texture.

```cs
File fileData;
Texture2d txture;
if (File.Exists(URLImg))     {
         fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(URLImg); //read the bytes from the file at URLImg's destination
         txture = new Texture2D(0,0);//makes the new texture
         txture.LoadImage(fileData);//loads the image from the file
         view.Img.sprite = Sprite.Create(txture, new Rect(0,0,200,200), new Vector2());
         //set Img.sprite to a new sprite at 0,0 with the dimensions 200x200
     }
```

with `view.Img.sprite` as an image rather than "text" because it's not painting text and rather an image.

Comment: For some reason, unity says "(30,30): error CS1002: ; expected"

Comment: I would need to see your code for that. it sounds like you're missing a semicolon @КаналShoker2

Comment: It maps to this location `(File.Exists(URLImg))`

Comment: @КаналShoker2 it seems like URLImg might not be a variable or something else may be wrong, again I would need to see at least the full method to see what's going wrong

Comment: I have updated the code in the question

Comment: @КаналShoker2 try to put "using System.IO" at the top of your code, this may fix it.

Comment: nothing has changed

Comment: @КаналShoker2 my bad. the part in the parentheses was supposed to be an if statement. I edited my answer.

Comment: Now he writes:
`Assets\Scripts\CreateMonumentButtons.cs(30,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'File' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: And:
`Assets\Scripts\CreateMonumentButtons.cs(32,13): error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @КаналShoker2 ```using System.IO.File;```

Comment: `A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'File' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead`

Comment: @КаналShoker2 when you put the if statement in did you remove ```using System.IO;```?

Comment: `Cannot declare a variable of static type 'File'`

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.IO.File'`

Comment: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IO.File' to 'byte[]'`

Comment: I found a solution.
I changed your code like this:
`Texture2D txture;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(URLImg))     {
            var fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(URLImg); //read the bytes from the file at URLImg's destination
            txture = new Texture2D(0,0);//makes the new texture
            txture.LoadImage(fileData);//loads the image from the file
            view.Image.sprite = Sprite.Create(txture, new Rect(0,0,200,200), new Vector2());
            //set Img.sprite to a new sprite at 0,0 with the dimensions 200x200
        }`

Answer (score 0):

[Unity Beginner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDp1an9rFfw) has explained it easily in just 1.5 minutes to [Load Image from WebLink or URL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDp1an9rFfw).

But here, they used WWW, which is obsolete, so use UnityWebRequest instead. [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195212/www-is-obsolete-use-unitywebrequest) are the changes you need to perform while changing from WWW to UnityWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple plugin for this.
If someone is interested, check this [repo](https://github.com/0kk470/Unity_UriImage)