# Allowing player to set profile picture and have others see it (unity netcode)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I want players to be able to click a button in settings that will allow them to set a pfp with an image on their pc. I have learned about EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel, but I don't know how to change the actual image after I get the image from the user, or how to send said image to the other players. I am working on a card game kinda like uno mobile or scrabble but it will run on a pc.
I am using netcode for game objects and multiplayer tools, unity 2021.3.6f1

I am expecting a player to be able to click a button, select a png or jpg, have a 2d sprite or 2d image change to said png/jpg, and have that png/jpg show up on other player's screens all while the game is running.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to upload user's profile picture to WEB server and instead of trying to share whole image share only link to the image.

Comment: ok, how would i sort of embed the image?
idk how to make unity display an image instead of it's link

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765518/how-to-load-an-image-from-url-with-unity) heres question aboud embeding image from the url, take a look on ansers