# Unity Engine freezes when trying to download an image from URL

Tags: unity-game-engine, imagedownload

I am writing a Pokemon TCG application, and I need to obtain card images at runtime from URLs (such as `https://images.pokemontcg.io/bw1/1.png`) in order to use them in sprite renderers. This **must** be done at runtime, because I won't know in advance which card images I will need.

To test my functions I used the url and a legacy button calling the `LoadSprite` funtion and a `SpriteRenderer`.
But, when calling following function, the unity editor froze completely.

```csharp
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer card;
    [SerializeField] private string url;
 public void LoadSprite()
    {
        GenerateCard setCardSprite = new GenerateCard();
        setCardSprite.SetImage(card,url);
    }
```

The `GenerateCard` class (unfinished):

```csharp
public class GenerateCard
{
    public void SetImage(SpriteRenderer card, string url)
    {
        Task<Texture2D> textureTask = DownloadImages.GetRemoteTexture(url);

        Texture2D cardimage = textureTask.Result;

        Rect rec = new Rect(0, 0, cardimage.width, cardimage.height);

        Sprite.Create(cardimage, rec, new Vector2(0, 0), 1);

        card.sprite = Sprite.Create(cardimage, rec, new Vector2(0, 0), .01f);
    }
}
```

I got the `DownloadImages` class with the `GetRemoteTexture` function from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766207).

I tried using `Debug.Log` to find out which line causes the freeze, but nothing gets sent to the console. I also replaced `(request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)` with the newer `(www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)`:

```sharp
public class DownloadImages
{

    public static async Task<Texture2D> GetRemoteTexture(string url)
    {
        Debug.Log("function was called");
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
        {
            // begin request:
            Debug.Log("begins request");
            var asyncOp = www.SendWebRequest();

            // await until it's done: 
            Debug.Log("start waiting");
            while (asyncOp.isDone == false)
                await Task.Delay(1000 / 30);//30 hertz
            Debug.Log("finished waiting");
            // read results:
            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
            // if( www.result!=UnityWebRequest.Result.Success )// for Unity >= 2020.1
            {
                // log error:
                #if DEBUG
                Debug.Log($"{www.error}, URL:{www.url}");
                #endif

                // nothing to return on error:
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                // return valid results:
                Debug.Log("Texture downloaded");
                return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope somebody knows why unity freezes and Thank You

Comment: im unsure which unity version you are using but usually a coroutine is the documented way to use the unitywebrequest class, I am not sure it is designed to work reliably as expected here

Comment: I use Unity version 2023.10f1
Thank you for the tipp, I will take a look at the docs

Comment: You should check out [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask), which is an asynchronous library made for unity.

Comment: @hijinxbassist but wouldn't that mean I should get it after the image is downloaded? or am i missing something? I let the program run for about 30 minutes and it didn't complete.

Comment: @BugFinder Thanks again for the tip, it works with a coroutine. I'll put the new Code into the Question.

Comment: I thought it was frozen only while downloading, ie blocked thread, my mistake\.

Comment: @Gurkenschnitzel I'd suggest removing your solution from the question, and instead putting that solution into an answer to this question (and then accepting that answer). This will indicate to everyone else that your question has now been answered (even if you answered it yourself)

Comment: Th original issue might be that one of the things you are awaiting needs to be on the Unity main thread (some of its API is not thread-safe) .. it might just silently throw an exception and never finish

Comment: @11belowstudio like this? I am pretty new to stack overflow so if it's missing something it would be nice if you can tell me

Comment: yep, you did it correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by using a Coroutine. The Sprite is very big and needs to be scaled down but it gets downloaded correctly.

```csharp
public IEnumerator DownloadImage(string MediaUrl, SpriteRenderer card)
    {
        Texture2D cardimage = null;
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(MediaUrl);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        else
            cardimage = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
        if (cardimage == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("cardimage is null");
        }
        Rect rec = new Rect(0, 0, cardimage.width, cardimage.height);
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(cardimage, rec, new Vector2(0, 0), 1);
        card.sprite = sprite;
    }
```